# Decompose symmetric matrix to scaling factors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a symmetric square matrix $P$ composed by left- and right-multiplying another symmetric square matrix $Z$ with a diagonal matrix $Λ$:

$$P = ΛZΛ$$

i.e. ($λ_i$ means $λ_{ii}$):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & \cdots & p_{1n} \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & \cdots & p_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
p_{n1} & p_{n2} & \cdots & p_{nn} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
λ_1λ_1z_{11} & λ_1λ_2z_{12} & \cdots & λ_1λ_nz_{1n} \\
λ_2λ_1z_{21} & λ_2λ_2z_{22} & \cdots & λ_2λ_nz_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
λ_nλ_1z_{n1} & λ_nλ_2z_{n2} & \cdots & λ_nλ_nz_{nn} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is there a decomposition able to do the reverse operation (going from $Z$ and $P$ to $Λ$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know $Z$ and $P$, then by comparing $z_{ii}$ and $p_{ii}$ (unless they are $0$), you can find $\lambda_i^2$...

Comment: ugh, of course. i was simply confused by the redundancy. $λ_i = \sqrt{p_{ii} ÷ z_{ii}}$